# Process multiple passed parameters

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am passing a parameter to a program that is based on the following code. The code calls a method of a specific class based on the parameter value. I would like to expand this to allow multiple parameters. What sort of code is needed that will allow to pass multiple parameters as well keeping the current functionality?

```
if (args != null && args.Length > 0)
{
    if (args[0] == "1")
    {
        Order.RunOrder();
    }
    if (args[0] == "2")
    {
        Shipment.RunShipment();
    }
    if (args[0] == "3")
    {
        Acknowledgments.RunAcknowledgments();
    }
    if (args[0] == "4")
    {
        Invoices.RunInvoices();
    }
}
else
{
    Helper.AddtoLogFile("------ No program type parameter found");
}
Helper.AddtoLogFile("-------Program Ends ----------");
return 0;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`args` is just an array of arguments, therefore you always have support for multiple parameters. Currently you are starting your application with

```
foo.exe 4
```

but you can also start it with

```
foo.exe 4 DoSomethingFancyWithBar
```

and then the code would look like this for example

```
if (args != null && args.Length > 1)
{
  if (args[1] == "DoSomethingFancyWithBar")
  {
     // do something fancy with the bar here
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have each of your `SomeClass.DoSomething()` methods take a `string[] args` parameter. Then you can store all of the parameters except the first: `var argsRest = args.Skip(1).ToList()` (you'll need to be using Linq for this) and then you can pass the args on: `SomeClass.DoSomething(argsRest)`.

This will let you have your main deal with selecting which class to call, then leave each of those classes to decide how it wants to handle the rest of the args.